LARAVEL 9. ERROR LARAVEL: 403 Forbidden You do not have permission to access this document. When writting "----" characters in field
I have developed a website with Laravel 9.X, which works correctly locally, but on my Host, I am having problems with an input, when I try to make an update.
I have some input fields in an edit page, that sometimes works, and sometimes not. I have been investigating why this happens, and I have seen that it fails when I type ---- in any field.
I guess it could be because it is interpreted as if it is SQL injection and tries to access some path that should not be outside the public folder.
In my controller, I pick up the request as follows:
public function update(Request $request) {

    $file->description = $request->description;

    // More fields and comprobations
 
    $file->save();

}

I wonder if there is a way to control this, or should I remove this type of characters in the frontend as in the backend.

This problem is not related to laravel. Most likely some some bogus software is "guarding" against "malicious" input

@YourCommonSense Closing the question was helpful, since you provided me with the link to the "duplicate" question, I managed to find out about ModSecurity, which my hosting was using without me knowing it.  I have found out that it is really useful, and that was what is denying the connection.
